# What can I do to use clangd in vscode to develop code about qemu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, qemu, clangd

Currently, I am using VS Code to write QEMU-related code. I use the clangd plugin, which requires the compile_command.json file. Although I generated this file with the appropriate command `ninja -t compdb > compile_commands.jso`, clangd still cannot prompt correctly. Additionally, I would like to use clang-format to format the code, but I cannot locate the .clang-format file that QEMU is using. I am also curious about the code formatting tool that QEMU developers use.

I want to know how the QEMU developers write the code especially what they use to debug and format the code.

Comment: This doesn't seem like the best venue to ask, because most QEMU developers aren't going to read this. You could try the qemu-devel mailing list. Personally, I use emacs...

Comment: If you attach [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) to your question, that might contain some clues about the first issue (clangd not prompting correctly). Not sure about the formatting questions

Comment: You shouldn't need to manually generate a compile_commands.json, because when you build QEMU that will create one for you in the build directory.

Comment: @PeterMaydell Thank you for your comment. I was able to locate the compile_commands.json file, but clangd is still not working perfectly. The main issue appears to be the numerous configurations (#ifdefs) that make it difficult for clangd to determine what is happening. Currently, there are no issues with clangd or qemu, but Emacs is not suitable for me right.  I think I will just disable the code hint in vscode.

Comment: @HighCommander4 Thank you as well. As for the formatting question, I think that developers have to maintain good formatting practices through self-awareness. Some code is too old for auto-formatting tools, which can cause many issues. However, I will 
also trying the qemu-devel mailing list for more assistance, since there some wrong code styles in qemu right now.